# Upgrade from K9 to 11, and passing by K10

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I want to Upgrade from Kentico 9 to Kentico 11 ans skipping upgrade K9 to K10. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot (and should not) do this.

> Please note: The upgrade procedures are **not** cumulative and you may need to use several upgrade procedures if you're using an old version of Kentico.

https://devnet.kentico.com/download/upgrades

While it may seem like this will save you time, the upgrade scripts are designed only to work between major versions  (7 > 8, 8 > 9, 9 > 10 etc.).  If you try to run the v11 script on a v9 database, you can expect failures in the upgrade process.

Running through each upgrade in order will reduce the risk here and give you the confidence that your site has migrated correctly.

Read the release notes before you start and make note of the breaking changes (there are quite a few)

- [Kentico 10 Release Notes](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/release-notes-kentico-10)
- [Kentico 11 Release Notes](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/release-notes-kentico-11)

Comment: Additionally one must run and open the site in a browser after each version upgrade . When handling the first request, the system performs certain tasks required to finalize the upgrade.

Comment: It is also good practice to apply the latest [hotfix](https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes) version after you have upgraded to v11.

Answer (score 2):

It is strongly recommended not to do that. You **must** always upgrade one version (major version) in ahead.

Best regards,
Dragoljub